# how to limit CreateCell c# procedural grid generation unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I am learning C# for unity and could use some pointers.

I am following catlikecoding hex map tutorial but I have modified the grid for my own means.

http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map-1/

My goal is to create a pyramid of squares procedurally starting from a 7 * 7 grid. I am using a prefab plane

How do I place a limit on The `CreateCell` looped function so that cells with the (x,y) coordinates are not created when they meet the following expression

```
x + y > n - 1 where n = grid size (for example (6,1) or (5,6)
```

I have gotten as far as creating a rhombus of planes with the undesired planes below the ground plane.

The script is as follows.

public class HexGrid : MonoBehaviour {

```
public int width = 7;
public int height = 7;
public int length = 1;


public SquareCell cellPrefab;
public Text cellLabelPrefab;

SquareCell[] cells;

Canvas gridCanvas;

void Awake () {
    gridCanvas = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();

    cells = new SquareCell[height * width * length];

    for (int z = 0 ; z < height; z++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
                CreateCell(x, z, y);
        }
    }
}

void CreateCell(int x, int z, int y) {
    Vector3 position;
    position.x = x * 10f ;
    position.y = ((y + 1) - (x + z)) * 10f + 60f;
    position.z = z * 10f ;

    Cell cell = Instantiate<Cell>(cellPrefab);
    cell.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
    cell.transform.localPosition = position;

    Text label = Instantiate<Text>(cellLabelPrefab);
    label.rectTransform.SetParent(gridCanvas.transform, false);
    label.rectTransform.anchoredPosition =
        new Vector2(position.x, position.z);
    label.text = x.ToString() + "\n" + z.ToString();
}
}
```

Grid so far
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add an `if` statement before the part of the code that creates a cell. In this case the method `CreateCell()`. That if statement should have your logic in code. You would also have to create two variables for the size to check. For example:

```
public int tempX;
public int tempY;
void Awake () {
gridCanvas = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();

cells = new SquareCell[height * width * length];

for (int z = 0 ; z < height; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
            {
                if (x + y < (tempX + tempY) - 1)
                {
                    CreateCell(x, z, y);
                }
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: _public int tempY;_                                                                                   _int 'TempY = height'_                                 and _'if (x + y < tempY)'_                         created the solution i was after. Thanks @Hristo